# ionic2: which component to design bottom popover

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

What component should I use to design like that bottom component in ionic2: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native `Social Sharing` plugin from [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/). It automatically creates the right sharing pop-up for all available platforms (iOS, Android and Windows Phone).

Comment: I saw it but I understand that I should use it to develop the app like share to facebook or other but what about the design?

Comment: What is your purpose? If you want to let the user share something, then use this plugin. The design is native for every platform. If you want to create a pop-up for something else, let me know.

Comment: I don't want to know the functionality of sharing data to social media, I want to know which component should I use to make like this design.

Comment: You probably need to create the component on your own, as far as I know. This pop-ups are used for social sharing. Something similar would be Actions Sheets from ionic: https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#action-sheets

Comment: yes I used it but I can't change it's design, I think it is a custom design

Comment: Their purpose is to be in a native design the device it's running on.